# can i copy viewpage and add webpart to be used by library feature

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part

i am copying viewpage.aspx and using newviewpage in setuppath for library feature (so views and allitems still work) i have a visual webpart i want to add to the newviewpage.aspx. can i even do this?
(does SharePoint allow it)
using sharepoint 2016 and visual studio 2022

the goal was to allow me to call custom code behind on click of column field entry of a library feature (not a single list), but any instantiated from deployed feature.
i wasnt sure if i should edit allitems.aspx template   for a library feature upon creation. (not sure how it gets created in the first place.) but ran into issues.